# UITableViewCell with KVO

Tags: uitableview, key-value-observing

I have a custom table view cell and it also observes a key of another object by using the method:

```
[_anotherObject addObserver:myCell
                 forKeyPath:@"killed"
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:0];
```

`_anotherObject` is an ivar in my custom table view cell class.

I know that I should remove `myCell` as an observer at some point, but I don't know when I should do.

As far as I know, possible places are: `-dealloc` & `-prepareForReuse`

Answer (score 0):

Add a dealloc method to your UITableViewCell subclass:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    for (AnotherObject *object in self.subviews) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[AnotherObject class]]) {
            [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"killed"];
        }
    }
}
```

Something similar should work for you. That way you won't get those nasty "An instance 0x21bb1010 of class AnotherObject was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it," messages anymore.